# Node express request queue length

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way to find the web request queue length when a lot of requests hit an express server route at the same time?

I can use the listener stats from Unix but I'm looking for a more native way to do it.

Comment: Are you asking how to set the size of the request queue length for your server or are you asking how to query dynamically how many requests are currently in the queue?

Comment: @jfriend00 the later.

Answer (score 1):

This is achieved very easily. Somewhere in your program, you create a HTTP server like this:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
```

All you need is to track incoming connections and count how many of them are open concurrently. I suppose you to store that number in `app.connectionsN` field

```
app.connectionsN = 0;

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
  // Increase connections count on newly estabilished connection
  app.connectionsN ++;

  socket.on('close', function() {
    // Decrease connections count on closing the connection
    app.connectionsN --;
  });
});
```